# Unable to enter design view in SSMS 2012 when accessing SQL Azure database

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms

How can I enter design view in SQL Server Management Studio 2012 on my tables when accessing windows azure database?

[image: SSMS]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, SSMS 2012 doesn't support many of the nice features when connected to Azure SQL DBs.

However, VS2013 does support a lot more features.  Connect the DB in the SQL Server Object Explorer of VS2013 and you can get a similar design view.

Answer (score 1):

You can't at the moment. 
You're restricted to using T-SQL or, alternatively, the web-based management portal which does provide design capabilities for Windows Azure SQL Database or Visual Studio Object Explorer

Comment: Exploring data is now difficult. Without the designer building queries with all the relationships is a pain in the ass. The designer is a useful tool. Tools are what we use as engineers. They need to fix it.

If a solution to this problem does not include being able to easily build queries then it's not a solution at all.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the web based portal to edit the table if you already have data.

Otherwise, drop and recreate the table via T-SQL.

You can execute TSQL from both SSMS 2012 or the web based portal with no issues.

**ANSI SQL is the only way to fly!**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [db Forge Studio by devart](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/studio/). The trial version is limited by some export-funcionality, otherwise its free up to 1 year. Licenses starts at 150$

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with SSMS 2012
But with Navicat for SQL Server all Design and browse feature are allowed